# Alignment of geometry nodes instances in Blender

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created 2 empties. Using geometry nodes on another single vertex object, I created a mesh line joining these empties. When i try to instance a cone on this mesh line, i am unable to align it to the tangent.

[image: Instance of pyramid on a mesh line]

But i am able to align it if I use a curve line instead of a mesh line.

Is it possible to do it using the mesh line instead of the curve line?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Node [Edge Vertices](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/edge_vertices.html) and calculate the direction vector between the points. You can then convert this direction vector into a rotation using [Align Euler to Vector](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/align_euler_to_vector.html). However, I would still use a curve if possible.

Comment: @quellenform can you please elaborate the Blender Geometry Nodes method of "calculate the direction vector between the points"? I saw lot of complicated trigonometry over the internet, but could not translate it into Blender Geometry Nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you just have to calculate the direction vector between the points with the vector math node `Substract`, and convert it to a rotation with the node `Align Euler to Vector`.

You have two possibilities:

Either you use the node `Edge Vertices` and calculate the vector between each point:

[image]

Or you use directly the *Location* of the *Empties*:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>